# Why can not read inbox of gmail?

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I need to check mails from gmail for my behat tests.
I used this [tutorial](https://arjunphp.com/reading-emails-from-gmail-using-php-imap/) to get my emails from gmail with php:

```
set_time_limit(4000);

// Connect to gmail
$imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'your_email_id@gmail.com';
$password = 'your_gmail_password';

// try to connect
$inbox = imap_open($imapPath,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

   /* ALL - return all messages matching the rest of the criteria
    ANSWERED - match messages with the \\ANSWERED flag set
    BCC "string" - match messages with "string" in the Bcc: field
    BEFORE "date" - match messages with Date: before "date"
    BODY "string" - match messages with "string" in the body of the message
    CC "string" - match messages with "string" in the Cc: field
    DELETED - match deleted messages
    FLAGGED - match messages with the \\FLAGGED (sometimes referred to as Important or Urgent) flag set
    FROM "string" - match messages with "string" in the From: field
    KEYWORD "string" - match messages with "string" as a keyword
    NEW - match new messages
    OLD - match old messages
    ON "date" - match messages with Date: matching "date"
    RECENT - match messages with the \\RECENT flag set
    SEEN - match messages that have been read (the \\SEEN flag is set)
    SINCE "date" - match messages with Date: after "date"
    SUBJECT "string" - match messages with "string" in the Subject:
    TEXT "string" - match messages with text "string"
    TO "string" - match messages with "string" in the To:
    UNANSWERED - match messages that have not been answered
    UNDELETED - match messages that are not deleted
    UNFLAGGED - match messages that are not flagged
    UNKEYWORD "string" - match messages that do not have the keyword "string"
    UNSEEN - match messages which have not been read yet*/

// search and get unseen emails, function will return email ids
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

$output = '';

foreach($emails as $mail) {
$headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$mail);
$output .= $headerInfo->subject.'<br/>';
$output .= $headerInfo->toaddress.'<br/>';
$output .= $headerInfo->date.'<br/>';
$output .= $headerInfo->fromaddress.'<br/>';
$output .= $headerInfo->reply_toaddress.'<br/>';
$emailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$mail);
if(!isset($emailStructure->parts)) {
$output .= imap_body($inbox, $mail, FT_PEEK);
} else {
    //
}
   echo $output;
   $output = '';
}

// colse the connection
imap_expunge($inbox);
imap_close($inbox);
```

But this error occures all the time:

“*Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream*”

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723068/open-email-by-php-using-imap-giving-me-this-error-message-imap-open-function), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677764/sudden-php-error-warning-imap-open-function-imap-open-couldnt-open-strea) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244967/mac-os-x-mavericks-php-error-imap-open-function-imap-open-couldnt-open-s) question. But they all did not help me.

**What else could be the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

After checking my account I got emails from GMail, that it blocked login tries of unsecure connections.

So I figured out that you have to allow unsecure connection in your security settings:

[image]

Et voilá! It works and I can continue my behat test writing.

Answer (score 0):

go to mailbox setting , choose Imap/pop transfert , enable  imap , next you will receive a message from gmail , confir that you make this change and all wil work fine.